# Xcode: How to set current working directory to a relative path for an executable?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have a command-line executable in Xcode.

I am using Xcode 5.1. In the "Scheme Editor" for the project under "Options" there is an option for "Working Directory". How can I specify a path relative to the .xcodeproj file? I have tried a single period.

I need this because the code needs to assume the existence of  files relative to the project directory.

Comment: This is a command-line utility for the project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [Xcode build setting variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW105) such as `PROJECT_DIR`, e.g. setting your working directory to `$PROJECT_DIR/..` will make it equal to the parent directory of your project directory.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode preferences you can change the location of the compiled binaries to be relative to your project, or at any absolute path you like. Go to `Preferences`->`Locations` and then click on the `Advanced...` button below the `Derived Data` text field.

In the sheet that pops up set the `Build Location` to `Custom`, and then select the desired option in the nearby dropdown, and enter whatever paths you like in the `Products` field.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode Derived Data location diaglog]

Answer (score 0):

For new version Xcode (here `14.3.1`):

`Xcode`->`Product`->`Scheme`->`Edit Scheme...`->`Run->Run`->`Options` tab ->`Working Directory`-> choose/select: `Use custom working directory`, set to value: `$(SOURCE_ROOT)`

[image]

Comment: Note that these steps have been valid for several years. It's not new to Xcode 14.3.1.