# Xcode template to import file by file path

Tags: ios, xcode, templates

I have a Xcode template file like so:

```
#import "___FILEBASENAME___.h"

@implementation ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___
@end
```

This will create an example file like so:

```
#import "ExampleFile.h"

@implementation ExampleFile
@end
```

However due to some complexity in our build system, I need to import files by their file path.

For example, if I was creating `ExampleFile.m` inside of `Path/To/` folder. Then my desired output would be:

```
// Desired template output
#import "Path/To/ExampleFile.h"
```

I tried looking through some Apple example templates, but didn't seem to find a way to make it work.

I also stumpled upon `___DIRECTORY___` referenced [here](https://github.com/NSBoilerplate/Xcode-Project-Templates/wiki/Creating-Xcode-4.x-Project-Templates#constants), but it doesn't seem to work for me when I attempted to use it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish this?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work for me when I attempted to use it." How, exactly, does it not work? Does it render the wrong path? Or does it not render at all, and leave it as `___DIRECTORY___`? What exactly does the code read as, what string is being rendered, and what were you expecting instead?

Comment: It doesnt parse it at all. So "___DIRECTORY___" appears verbatim in the generated file.

Comment: So, just to be absolutely clear, your code says `"___DIRECTORY___/___FILEBASENAME___.h"`, and it's outputting as `"___DIRECTORY___/ExampleFile.h"`?

Comment: Correct. (character limit)

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling "Use custom working directory" option, it will let you choose the base directory. 
How to enable this is answered in the following question.
[Xcode: How to set current working directory to a relative path for an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143930/xcode-how-to-set-current-working-directory-to-a-relative-path-for-an-executable)

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context. It looks like the solution you're referring to would just change the location for build products. How do I reference this in the xctemplate?

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Could you please let me know whether this is a Project Template or a File template?

Comment: This is a File template. To create a .m file.

My issue is that we hook into some custom scripts that rely on the absolute import path. So if I have file `This/Is/An/Example/Path/MyFile.h` and I want to create a `MyFile.m`, I need it to have an import like `#import "This/Is/An/Example/Path/MyFile.h"`.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma can't we do that using the programming language (swift)?

Comment: I'm working in Objective-C. However I'm not sure what you mean. The template file's in Xcode are not programmable in Objective-C as far as I know.